# How to add specific integer in the output text after certain period of time?

Tags: python, input, time

```
    enter code here

user_will = input("enter the name ")
if user_will == "giant":
    remainder = (10 - 4)
print("the remaining  are", remainder )
```

I want to add 1 in remainder every two seconds pass. Eventually to 10 .

Comment: I am a beginner coder in python. Sorry in advance if I have asked a dumb question.

Comment: Use  import time. Then do this time.sleep(2000) for 2 sec